# Consequence Limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $0 \le q \le 1$ and

[image]

Guess the limits of the sequences $(a_k)_{k∈\mathbb{N}}$, $(b_k)_{k∈\mathbb{N}}$ and $(c_k)_{k∈\mathbb{N}}$ and prove the convergence.

I need your help with problem. I don't know how to start to determine the limit value other than using $n$ numbers

Comment: what do you mean by "using n numbers"? The limits of at least the first two sequences should be clear, no? For the third one it might help to write $n = \log_{10}(k)$

Comment: Thank you for your commment. I mean I don't know how to start finding the limit other than substituting the number n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a_k$ and $b_k$ you should note, that $\frac{1}{k^2}$, $\frac{1}{k}$ and $q^k$ get smaller as $k$ gets larger (unless $q=1$, you have to make a case distinction there), that should help you guessing the limit. For $c_k$ you can substitute $n = \log_{10}(k)$ in the second case and then use $k \geq \log_{10}(k)$ to find
\begin{align*}
0 \leq c_k \leq \frac{1}{\log_{10}(k)}
\end{align*}
that should help determining the limit.